# How should we tag the insurance question?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/22/should-i-purchase-pet-insurance) about pet insurance is currently tagged [dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs), which is wrong -- there's nothing dog-specific in the question.  Presumably this is because it needed to be tagged with *something* and "insurance" is too specific.

How should this question be tagged?

Comment: Health is the first that comes to mind. Veterinary Care might be another option.

Comment: Finances, Expenses, or either two @JohnCavan recommends.

Comment: "pet-insurance", as a tag, is a viable one. As I have stated before, due to their high advertisement in the United States, and the apparent push from some veterinarian agencies, there will be MANY more questions about this topic than you could possibly anticipate at this time of private beta.  I'll let the site discover that gem on its own when it shines brightly in a couple of weeks.

Comment: I don't understand why questions asking "how should we handle *x*" are being downvoted... I could understand if the question were posing a solution, as I would then expect the downvote to indicate that someone disagreed with the proposed solution, but this question offers no specific suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Posting [pet-insurance](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pet-insurance) as suggested in the comment by @JoshDM as an answer, so it can be properly voted on.  [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASPCA_Pet_Insurance) on Wikipedia claims more than half a million policies in North America in 2005.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) and [pet-insurance](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pet-insurance).  Both are relevant to the question, and both may be useful tags for people browsing.